# Switch Off lights a .fbx model in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, light, fbx

I'm loading a .fbx model in my threejs scene, but it has a very hard light inside. How could I switch off or modify the light inside the model?
I've tried to access it via object and child.Mesh, but i can't get any information...

```
    loader.load( 'fbxmodel.FBX', function ( object ) {
            // mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
            // var action = mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 0 ] );
            // action.play();
            object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child.isMesh ) {
                    child.castShadow = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                    console.log(child.light) //Undefined
                }
            });
            console.log(object.light) //Undefined
            scene.add( object );
        });
```

Comment: Can you inspect the model first with FBX viewer or some software like Blender? This way it's easier to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Good idea @andypotato. I'm going to try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if exist any way to do this in threejs. I have opened the file in blender, switch off the light and export again the .fbx